# Set url parameter in route (Symfony 2.6)

Tags: php, symfony

So, lets assume i got this `showAction()` in my `DisplayController.php`:

```
/**
 * @param $type
 * @param $slug
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function showAction($type, $slug)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Usually, the following route links to this action:

```
my_bundle_display_show:
    pattern: /display/{type}/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: MyFunnyBundle:Display:show }
```

So, when I request `my-website.com/display/product/A`, everything works as intended.

However, now I need to implement a quicklink which requires me to skip the `type` argument which looks like `my-website.com/specific-product`  which is supposed to link to `my-website.com/display/product/specific-product`. The route i created for that looks like that:

```
my_bundle_display_show_specific_product:
    pattern: /{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: MyFunnyBundle:Display:show }
    requirements:
        slug: "specific-product"
    defaults:
        type: "product"
```

The specific error messages is `Controller "MyBundle\Controller\DisplayController::showAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$type" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).`

However, that doesn't work since I'm required to add a `$type` in order for it to work. I could create a new `showSpecificProductAction`, but I don't want to do that since both functions basically do the same. So I was wondering if i can "set" variables within routes so I can basically only make `$slug` an actual variable without editing the `showAction()` itself?

Comment: In the second code snippet, you've set `type` param correctly, but you gave it value `display` while it seems you should set to `product`.

Comment: @dragoste ty for the hint, however, that's not the problem. I was just simplifying the entire code in order to make it easier for anyone who might be able to help me to understand. I get the error Controller `"MyBundle\Controller\DisplayController::showAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$type" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one). `

Comment: But the second snippet **is the correct syntax** do to this. Do you get this error with `type: "product"`?

Comment: What else do you need to display in your route that is not a product ? Maybe you are trying to hard to factor your code and should use a showProductAction($slug) for the purpose of displaying products.

Comment: @np87 I simply don't want to create another action for something which i pretty much already have, these were 2 pretty similar ones. However, I handled this via a redirect now, I'll add the solution tomorrow in this post and close it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller action, change the function to
`public function showAction($type='product', $slug)`

Comment: It's incorrect syntax to provide default value for arguments that are before arguments without it. You can't use of it, because you need to pass some value while calling the method anyway, to be able to pass value for the second  argument.

Comment: Your are right of course, my bad! But shouldn't swapping both arguments help in that case? I'm fairly sure that I once solved OPs problem with that approach..

Answer (score 0):

Do not search for easier/shorter solutions. Make thing correctly and you won't have problems in future.

First, define your routing logic/aim. If you want a short url to redirect you to a full page, than do exactly this. You could do this in yaml right away with:

```
my_bundle_display_show_specific_product:
    path: /{slug}/
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: my_bundle_display_show
        permanent: true
        type: "some default value"
```

If you don't know the default type value, just create new action in controller, find the value and redirect from controller providing this value and using proper HTTP code. Such redirects are good for SEO as well:

```
public function actionOne($slug) {
    $type = ... // find out the type
    return $this->redirectToRoute('actionTwo', ['type' => $type, 'slug' => $slug], 301);
}

public function actionTwo($type, $slug) {
    // do some stuff...
}
```

If you DO need both urls to work, just create 2 routes configuration and 2 actions. But since they have common logic, create a private method in controller, which will do the logic for both. This is what OOP is all about:

```
public function actionOne($slug) {

    $type = ... // find out the type

    return $this->renderProduct($type, $slug);
}

public function actionTwo($type, $slug) {
    return $this->renderProduct($type, $slug);
}

private function renderProduct($type, $slug) {
     return $this->render('view', [...]);
}
```

Think of a logic first, then separate logical parts (using route/controller/action). This is what it is all about. Good luck!